# How do phonon modes and other collective atom processes fit in with the Clausius-Mossotti relation?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics

The [Clausius-Mossotti Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Mossotti_relation) relates the molecular polarizability of a chemical (that is, how much an electric field polarizes the molecule) to its dielectric constant, which determines its optical properties. Intuitively, this makes sense to me: light is an oscillating E field, so seeing how much a single atom responds to an E field (polarizability) should tell you how a material made of those atoms will respond to light (permittivity).

But then, you can take into account the [phonon modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#Acoustic_and_optical_phonons) of the crystal lattice. These can interact with light and affect the optical properties, meaning they affect the permittivity. However, they aren't a result of the polarizability of a single atom -- it's a phenomenon that only arises as a result of multiple atoms.

So what's happening here? It the C-M Relation just some 1st order approximation? Or is there some subtlety to it, like the phonon modes actually being included in the polarizability?

Comment: Clausius-Mossotti is a T=0 theory of polarizable media. A phenomenological extension for ferroelectric materials can be done with Ginsburg-Landau theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity, but you are looking for a microscopic theory, right?

Comment: @CuriousOne, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying... Phonon modes should still exist at T = 0, right?

Comment: Yes, Phonon modes still exist at T=0, they are not excited, though. If you were doing a phonon based model, you would probably do it including thermodynamic excitations, that's why I mentioned it. I have simply not seen a worked out approach to this, so I can't point you to it. Ferromagnetism seems to be all the rage with the theoreticians but not many seem to be interested with ferroelectricity, even though I do agree that it should be treated equally.

Comment: @CuriousOne, hmm, well, they're not inherently excited by temperature fluctuations at T = 0, that's what you mean, right? But I was talking about exciting them with incident light, which should still be able to happen at T = 0 then, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean... like I said, I did a short literature search after I saw your question and I couldn't fined anything that I liked... I am sure someone must have done it, I just don't know about it. T=0 theory is not very interesting and it is unphysical for thermodynamic reasons. Truthfully, once one excites a phonon, it thermalizes anyway, so it's not like one can do meaningful measurements on these system at T=0, anyway. The theory for finite T should be fully worked out, including phonons... the only question is which textbook has it?